# How to get parent sku from child sku magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, sku

I have a child SKU in an array and I need to get all the parents from the existing child SKUs from the array.
Can everybody help me ?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429409/9868522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get parent SKU directly using child sku.

- First, call
  `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::getIdBySku` to get
  child product id by sky.
- Then  Parent product id  by child Product id.`\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable::getParentIdsByChild`.

After that find parent skus by  Parent Product id. `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::getProductsSku`

### Code Sample:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    private $resourceProduct;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
     */
    private $resourceConfigurable;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceProduct,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $resourceConfigurable
    ){
        $this->resourceProduct = $resourceProduct;
        $this->resourceConfigurable = $resourceConfigurable;
    }
    
    public function test()
    {
        $childSku = 'child-MB-Configurable';
    
        $childId = $this->resourceProduct->getIdBySku($childSku);
    
        if ($childId) {
    
            $parentIds = $this->resourceConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
            if (!empty($parentIds)) {
                $skus = $this->resourceProduct->getProductsSku($parentIds);
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($skus);
            }
    
        }
    }
```